# Declare textfield variables to work multiple times in a if statement (swift4)

Tags: swift, variables, if-statement, declaration

My code below is in a textfield button. The problem is that the val1 to val3 can only be used in one if statement. How can I declare the vars to be used multiple times within that `if` statement?

```
if let val1 = Int(a1.text!), let val2 = Int(a2.text!), let val3 = Int(b1.text!) {
    let sum = val1 + val2
    let sum2 = val1  + val3
}
if a2.text == "$" {
    a1.text = String(sum2)
}
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. First you state (correctly) that val1 - val3 can only be used within the one `if` statement. Then you ask how to use them within that `if` statement. The code you posted is fine. Please clarify what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the values of val1 and val3 in which case you can declare them as var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since you use optional binding to declare the constants val1, val2, and val3, they can only be used in that first if statement.

As for constants sum and sum2, they are declared within the first if statement, so you cannot access them from the second if statement.

If accessing sum and sum2 in the second if statement is what you want to do, then declare sum and sum2 OUTSIDE of the first if statement as such:

```
var sum: Int = 0
var sum2: Int = 0

if let val1 = Int(a1.text!), let val2 = Int(a2.text!), let val3 = Int(b1.text!) {
    sum = val1 + val2
    sum2 = val1  + val3
}

if a2.text == "$" {
    a1.text = String(sum2)
}
```

Now this way you're declaring sum and sum2 as global variables, so you can access them anywhere in the file.

If you want to access val1, val2, or val3 in the second if statement, you can't. You're going to have to restructure your code if you want to do that.